# comma separated string with Advance Search

Tags: sql, ruby, search, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging

I've added an Advance Search to my Book App using this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised). Everything works fine, but now I am trying to find a Book by its Tags.

I got the advance search to work if the user enters one Tag into the :keywords text_field.

Is there a way to search various tags by splitting the keyword string with commas?

```
(ex: fun, kid stories, action) 
Would allow me to search books with fun OR kids stories OR actions.
```

**How can I search multiple tags via a comma separated string?**

Note: I created a search method that I think could help, but I am not sure how to combine it with the single keyword search.

**MODEL**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_mappings
  has_many :tags, through: :book_mappings

end


class BookMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_mappings
  has_many :books, through: :book_mappings

end


class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  def books
    @books ||= find_books
  end

  def find_books
    books = Book.order(:name)

    ###This works for a single word but NOT if I have multiple tags separated by commas
    books = books.joins(:tags).where("tags.name like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?

    books
  end

  def search(keywords)
     return [] if keywords.blank?
     cond_text = keywords.split(', ').map{|w| "name LIKE ? "}.join(" OR ")    
     cond_values = keywords.split(', ').map{|w| "%#{w}%"}
     all(:conditions =>  (keywords ? [cond_text, *cond_values] : []))
  end

end
```

**VIEWS**

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :keywords %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Just add a `like` statement for each keyword.

To filter books with all the tags

```
if keywords.present?
  books = books.joins(:tags)
  keywords.tr(' ','').split(',').each do |keyword|
    books = books.where("tags.name like ?", "%#{keyword}%") 
  end
end
```

To filter books with any of the tags

```
if keywords.present?
  books = books.joins(:tags)

  keyword_names = keywords.split(', ')
  cond_text = keyword_names.map{|w| "tags.name like ?"}.join(" OR ")
  cond_values = keyword_names.map{|w| "%#{w}%"}

  books = books.where(cond_text, *cond_values)
end
```

Comment: currently this gives me: (tags.name like '%fun%') AND (tags.name like '%action%') is there a way to use OR vs AND.  so that it essentially searches books that have either or vs both...

Comment: For some reason the Tags aren't being filtered correctly. SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` INNER JOIN `book_mappings` ON `book_mappings`.`book_id` = `books`.`id` INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `book_mappings`.`tag_id` ORDER BY `books`.name ASC

Comment: The OR code is actually giving me the entire book_mapping table.